# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I wanna scrape the site.

When I executed my code I got a problem.

Here is my code.

```
class good_auction(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driverPath = r"D:\python code\NaverBlogCralwer\NaverBlogCralwer\chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.driverPath)


    def main_scrape(self):
        self.driver.get('http://www.goodauction.com/index.php')
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('client_id').send_keys("myid")
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("pwd_dummy").send_keys('mypassword')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = good_auction()
    scraper.main_scrape()
```

and I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python code/auction_crawl/auction_crawler.py", line 36, in <module>
    scraper.main_scrape()
  File "D:/python code/auction_crawl/auction_crawler.py", line 27, in main_scrape
self.driver.find_element_by_id("pwd_dummy").send_keys('k1150719!!!')
  File "C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 347, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 491, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

How can I fix it??
Will I change my driver?? or Will I search for execute_script?? But I don't know javascript

Comment: You might want to edit out some sensitive data from your post (in your error log), I can't open the site, can you copy paste the page source in pastebin?

Comment: Thank~~ I solve it!!

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problems.

```
password = self.driver.find_element_by_id("pwd_dummy")
actions = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
actions.move_to_element(password)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys("mypassword")  # Replace with whichever keys you want.
actions.perform()
```

I use above code instead of below code.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("pwd_dummy").clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_id("pwd_dummy").send_keys('mypassword')
```